# Print the number increased by parameter passed, by passing the same number each time

Tags: javascript

```
function get_increased(number)
    {   
        console.log(number)
        number += number
    }
```

1st time called get_increased(1) \outputs 1 | desired output 1

2nd time called get_increased(1) \outputs 1 | desired output 2

3rd time called get_increased(1) \outputs 1 | desired output 3
and so on...

Condition: doesn't set any variable outside the function while declaring the function.

Comment: You receive `number` and only change `number`. If you want to persist the value, you need a different variable name, otherwise you only work with one every time.

Comment: Sounds like a lesson on closures

Comment: get rid of the passed in parameter and scaffolding will make it work like you want.  It will have scope to number from outside.  Either that or return the new value (return number;) and assign it to the passed in value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a variable outside of the function to hold the new values. Plus you need a different variable passed as your incremental value.

```js
number = 0;

function get_increased(inc) {
  number += inc
}

get_increased(1);
console.log(number);

get_increased(1);
console.log(number);
```

Comment: is it possible without setting a variable outside of the function?

Answer (score 0):

As @VLAZ said, the only way to persist the number is to allocate a variable for it. It is not the best practice, but I allocated the result in the window global variable.

```js
function get_increased(number) {   
 console.log('number: ', number)
 window._number = window._number ? window._number + number : number
 return window._number
}
    
console.log(get_increased(1))
console.log(get_increased(2))
console.log(get_increased(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do it, you would need to hold the value somewhere else. Typical patten looks like this:

```js
function tally (startingNumber) {
  console.log(startingNumber);
  return function (number) {
      startingNumber += number;
      console.log(startingNumber);
  }
}


var tally1 = tally(1);
tally1(1);
tally1(1);
tally1(1);

var tally2 = tally(3);
tally2(1);
tally2(2);
tally2(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'number' is not being incremented as expected.

There are 2 main problems in the given code. See the altered code below for 3 different scenarios

1. Javascript passes numbers by value, not by reference. The initial call to get_increased therefore is equivalent to get_increased(1) (I have assumed you have started with number=1 om the examples below). The function then uses a variable called number, but it is local to that function, it is not the var number declared initially. It outputs it to the console and then increases it by the value of itself (which happens to be 1) but that version of the variable number does not exist outside that instance of running get_increased

To increase a variable called number and have it persist until the next call of get_increased, and the next and the next.... we can declare it outside the function and have the function use it (both to get its value and to update its value) see the second set of script in the below code.

2. However, even if we make get_increased use this more persistent variable number, the line

   number += number

adds the value of number to itself - doubling the value each time so we see 1 2 4 8 etc in the console.log To increase the value by one the code is

```
 number +=1
```

which has the same meaning as

```
number = number + 1
```

Here are the 3 sets of script to try out

```
<script>
var number=1;
for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
  get_increased(number);
}
function get_increased(number)
    {   
        console.log(number);
        number += number; //number is local to the get_increased function
    }
</script>

<script>
var number=1;

for (var j=0;j<5;j++) {
  get_increased();
  }
function get_increased()
    {   
        console.log(number);
        number += number;//we are using the number defined above but the number is added to itself - giving a doubling each time
    }
</script>

<script>
var number=1;

for (var k=0;k<5;k++) {
  get_increased();
  }
function get_increased()
    {   
        console.log(number);
        number += 1;//this gives the result asked for
    }
</script>
```